# Sending and receiving that same data by the same program, over a network socket

Tags: java, sockets, localhost, synchronous, socketexception

I'm trying to send a data packet, and receive that same data packet, by a java program over a socket.
The point is to measure the time it takes to go over the network and return to my program itself.
I cannot use localhost "127.0.0.1".
I cannot use my own IP address, because it causes a `java.net.BindException` (with it saying the Address is already in use, which it is).

Is there any other way to do this?
I thought maybe partially closing the socket using `socket.shutDownOutput()`, but the problem is that I wish to send a lot of data packets, so the socket will need to listen to it synchronously.

Any way to do this? Send a data packet over a network and back to the same program/same IP Address.

Comment: The packets will never be sent over a network using localhost - it'll never leave your computer. Have you tried using another port? It has to be unused.

Comment: Are you trying to invent the Ping ?
Please explain what are your purposes and some line of codes can be great.

Comment: The purpose is to simulate different server client programs on a single computer. I'd require to pass on messages from one Client/Server node to another. Since it's a simulation, I'd prefer to use several threads running of the same program.

Comment: I was rather unclear about stating that I need the data packet to be handled by a different thread, and not the same program. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a client that echoes the data back to the server? Then you can bind it to any IP address.